# array_slice not working as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to build a random domain generator with title of current random domains and the random domains but I have a bit of problems with the logic so have build the following script and the current output is:

file.txt - CURRENT OUTPUT

```
# SomeTitleText
staffweb.hawthorn73.org on 2014-05-11
domain:
sunshineny.com    
# SomeTitleText
staffweb.hawthorn73.org on 2014-05-11
text:
sunshineny.com
text:
appsmylife.com
 . 
 .
 and goes like this and includes all the urls
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
# SomeTitleText first 10-20 domains separated by comma(random number of domains) on 
2014-05-11
text: sunshineny.com
text: appsmylife.com
 .
 .
// next 8/9/10/..20 domains (random between 10-20)
# SomeTitleText next 10-20 domains separated by comma (random number of domains) on 
2014-05-12
text: next **REMAINING** domains after the random domain and again random number of domains 
between 10-20 and stop if it finished all domains
```

The script:

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo) {
    $aryRange=array();
    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));
    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}
$urls1 = array(
    'http://samsung.gamechodt.com',
    'https://sunshineny.com',
    'http://www.appsmylife.com',
    'http://greenfirefarms.com',
    'http://gillesarbeau.com',
    'https://www.digitalpoint.com',
    'http://www.besttravel.com',
    'http://faceshapes101.wordpress.com',
    'http://www.exploteam.pl',
    'http://www.graficon.es',
    'http://shafatrasool.com',
    'http://xvnp.com',
    'http://en.seokicks.de',
    'http://nokia-2610.gamechodt.com',
    'http://ziiquam.606h.net',
    'http://www.hoyenfutbol.com',
    'http://doggoodsusa.com',
    'http://www.blackpaper.ch',
    'http://www.teflzorritos.com',
    'http://abovegravityonline.com',
    'http://staffweb.hawthorn73.org'
);
$domains = array();
foreach ($urls1 as $domain) {
    $domain = str_replace('http://www.', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('http://', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('https://www.', '', $domain);
    $domain = str_replace('https://', '', $domain);
    array_push($domains, $domain);
}
$file = fopen('disavow.txt', "w");
$i = 0;
$date_range = createDateRangeArray('2014-05-10','2015-04-10');
$text = '';
$domains_bad = array();
foreach ($urls1 as $bad_domain) {
    $i++;
    $random = range(10,20);
    shuffle($random);
    $range = range(1, count($urls1), $random[0]);
    if ($i <= count($urls1)) {
        $range_domain = $i + $range[$i];
    } else {
        break;
    }
    $bad_domain_range_array = array_slice($domains, $range_domain);
    $bad_domain_range = implode(', ', $bad_domain_range_array);
    if($i == $range[0]) {
        $domaintext = "# SomeTitleText $bad_domain_range on $date_range[$i] ".PHP_EOL;
        $text .= PHP_EOL.$domaintext.PHP_EOL;
        $text .= "text:".$domains[$i].PHP_EOL;
        unset($domains[$i]);
    } else {
        $text .= "text:".$domains[$i].PHP_EOL;
        unset($domains[$i]);
    }
    fwrite($file, $text);
}
```

Comment: Could you ad some use case scenario. Like: "I have array with these forbidden urls, as well as these other urls and I want to make a shuffled array out of it"?

Comment: error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function createDateRangeArray() in stackoverflow.php on line 36

Comment: @divaka It would be something like this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en, just that only on domains. And the number of domains + dates are random between 10-20.

Comment: Debug the code, find where execution flow starts to differ from what you expected. When you localized the bug other people may help you figure it out.

Comment: @Cthulhu trying for about 1 day.

Comment: error :: Undefined offset: 2 in line 60;

Comment: if you give me the working sample i will  try to work it out, im awake for another 20 minutes, im in australia its late

Comment: I appreciate the upvotes, but I think this is indeed a big programming problem, if after 50 views no answer, then required a lot of gray matter.

Comment: anyone please, still trying.

Comment: found a solution? why not post it here...